# Making function for a given input of sum of sequences, choose two sequence $a_i, b_j$ and substitute all other sequence zero

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

Suppose I have a sequence a,b,c,d,e,f,g and for given sequence  whose element is expressed as a1,a2,a3, ... , c1,c2,c3, ... g1,g2,g3, and so on.

And suppose from these sequence with some manipulation I have the following input

```
input = a1a2b1b2c2c3 + 100a1b2 + a1c2b2d3 + a1a2 + a3c1c2 + a3c1
```

Then I want to make a function that makes my specific variable be nonzero and all other variable be zero.

I want a function whose input is three variables such that only input variables are nonzero and others are zero

```
f[input, x3, y3] =  input/.->{x1->0, x2->0, x4->0, .... , y1->0, y2->0, y4->0, .... ]
```

For example, f[input, a1,a2] = a1a2,  and f[input, a1,b2]=100a1b2 and so on.

Are there any smart ways to implement this?

For some simple case I just did by my hand, i.e.,

```
inputa1a2=input/.{a3->0, b1->0, b2->0, c1->0, c2->0 c3->0}
```

But for many variables, I realized this is inefficient and there seems to be a nice way

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = a1 a2 b1 b2 c2 c3 + 100 a1 b2 + a1 c2 b2 d3 + a1 a2 + a3 c1 c2 + a3 c1;
```

**1.** [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) + [`Alternatives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) + [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html) + [`Variables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html):

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1 = # /. Alternatives @@ Complement[Variables @ #, {##2}] -> 0 &;
```

***Examples:***

```
f1[input, a1, a2]
```

> ```
> a1 a2
> ```

```
f1[input, a1, b2]
```

> ```
> 100 a1 b2
> ```

```
f1[input, a3, c1, c2]
```

> ```
> a3 c1 + a3 c1 c2
> ```

**2.** [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) + [`Alternatives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) + [`Variables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html):

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = # /. {a : Alternatives @@ {##2} -> a, Alternatives @@ Variables[#] -> 0} &;
```

***Examples:***

```
f2[input, a1, a2]
```

> ```
> a1 a2
> ```

```
f2[input, a1, b2]
```

> ```
> 100 a1 b2
> ```

```
f2[input, a3, c1, c2]
```

> ```
> a3 c1 + a3 c1 c2
> ```

**3.** [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) + [`FreeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html) + [`Alternatives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) + [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html) + [`Variables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html):

```
ClearAll[f3]
f3 = Select[FreeQ[Alternatives @@ Complement[Variables  @#, {##2}]]] @ # &;
```

***Examples:***

```
f3[input, a1, a2]
```

> ```
> a1 a2
> ```

```
f3[input, a1, b2]
```

> ```
> 100 a1 b2
> ```

```
f3[input, a3, c1, c2]
```

> ```
> a3 c1 + a3 c1 c2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Variables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html) with [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html).

With

```
input = a1 a2 b1 b2 c2 c3 + 100 a1 b2 + a1 c2 b2 d3 + a1 a2 + a3 c1 c2 + a3 c1;
```

Then

```
f[expr_, vars__] :=
 expr /. DeleteCases[Thread[Variables[expr] -> 0], Alternatives @@ {vars} -> 0]
```

and

```
f[input, a1, a2]
```

> ```
> a1 a2
> ```

```
f[input, a1, b2]
```

> 100 a1 b2

```
f[input, a3, c1, c2]
```

> a3 c1 + a3 c1 c2

Hope this helps.